# Adding New Arrays Changes Previous Ones?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that asks the users name, then repeats it, says how many letters are in the name, the first letter of the name, and what place in the alphabet the first letter in the name is. I have this so far, but when I introduced the new char alpha, the char name is changed, ie. name[0] automatically becomes alpha[0], or a. How do I solve this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char name[30];
    int y;

    std::cout << "What is your name? \n";    
    std::cin >> name;

    char p;
    int z=0;

    for (int i= 0; p = name[i], p != '\0'; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Calculating... \n";
        z = i+ 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Your name is " << name << '\n';
    std::cout << "You have " << z << " letters in your name \n";
    std::cout << "The first letter of your name is " << name[0] << '\n';

    char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    if (name[0] = alpha[0])
    {
        y = 1;
    }
    else
        for (y = 1 ; name[0] != alpha[y]; y++)
        {
        }

    std::cout << name[0] << " is the " <<  y << " letter of the alphabet \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (name[0] = alpha[0]`  maybe you wanted `if (name[0] == alpha[0]` The first condition  is always true because you are assigning `alpha[0]` to `name[0]`. A good compiler will warn you about that assignment in a condition. Second Why don't use the API `isalpha(name[i])` instead of writing down the alphabet in an array of character?

Answer (score 1):

What I recommend is to use class `std::string` and you can use its members like `std::string::length()` which retrieves the length of the string (number of characters). Also You don't need to store the alphabet in an array of character but instead use `isalpha`, `toupper`...

Here is an example:

```
std::string name;
std::cout << "name: ";
std::cin >> name;

std::cout << "Your name is: " << name << std::endl;
std::cout << "The first letter in your name is: " << name[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "The index of the first letter in your name is: " << (int)( toupper(name[0]) - 'A' + 1 ) << std::endl;
std::cout << "There are " << name.length() << " letters in your name" << std::endl;
```

You may think this is a bit complicated `(int)( toupper(name[0]) - 'A' + 1 )` but here is how it works:

- The user may enter a Small or Capital letter so I don't care so I convert it to capital e.g `a` becomes `A` so I subtract `A` from the actual letter and add 1 to get its index in the alphabet. e.g: If the user enters `hello`, `toupper` makes `h` to `H` then `H` - `A` gives the index of the letter in alphabet but indexed 0 so I add 1. So that `A` is 1 instead of 0 and `H` is 8 instead of 7...